# Another application launched from my app uses the same heap

Tags: android, performance, memory, static-members, android-lifecycle

I am launching an application for eg  : Box app from my application. on launch of the the box app. my app goes to background and when i come back to my application all the static objects like datbase instances and static models are getting reset because of memory issue.
How should i handle this.I understand that onsaveinstancestate can be used.But in my case i have to hold onto many static models and DB instamces etc.which i think should not be held in onsavedinstancestate.
One more thing which i noted is that box application uses the same heap for creating objects and the Allocated heap and free memory gets changed.why is it like that?it runs in a different process.

Comment: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

new heap: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

DB and static instances:

there's nothing you can do. Whenever the system needs memory it will reclaim the memory. You have to learn how to proper deal with DB connections, singletons and the activity life-cycle.